# Two placeholders inside modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a modal popup extender. Inside the panel I have two placeholders. Both are visible false. When I press a button and have code like
           `this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
            PlaceHolder2.Visible = false;`
The modal popup opens. When I have code like this:

```
this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        PlaceHolder1.Visible = false;
        PlaceHolder2.Visible = true;
```

The modal popup doesn’t open. How can solve this issue? I attach my asp.net code:

```
<asp:Button  ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" /> 

  <asp:ModalPopupExtender 
    ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" 
    TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
    OkControlID="btnUpdate"     BehaviorID="ModalPopupExtender1"   DropShadow="true"   
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
  </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="LightGray"  
         CssClass="modalPopup" Width="600px" Height="450px">
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" Visible="false" runat="server">


                      <table class="style1">
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                  &nbsp;</td>
                              <td>
                                  &nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                   Name:</td>
                              <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtThoughtName" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="r"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                  Description:</td>
                              <td>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="37" 
                            Rows="5" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" ValidationGroup="r"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>
                                   Date:</td>
                              <td>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender
                            ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate">
                        </asp:CalendarExtender><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtDate" 
                            ValidationGroup="r"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                          </tr>

                              <td>
                                  &nbsp;</td>
                              <td>
                                  &nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">
                                 <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                          OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Create" ValidationGroup="r" Width="100px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" onclick="btnCancel_Click" 
                          Text="Cancel" Width="100px" /></td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>
                      </asp:PlaceHolder>
                 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" Visible="false" runat="server">
                 <table class="style1">
                          <tr>
                              <td class="style6">
                                  Join a Group:</td>
                              <td>
                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                                      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="GroupName" 
                                      DataValueField="GroupId">
                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                                  &nbsp;
                                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Create a Group</asp:LinkButton>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="style6">
                                  &nbsp;</td>
                              <td>
                                  <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate3" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                                    Width="160px"  OnClick="btnUpdate2_Click" Text="Join Group" ValidationGroup="a" />
                                  &nbsp;
                                  <asp:Button ID="btnCancel3" runat="server" onclick="btnCancel2_Click" 
                                    Width="160px"  Text="Cancel" />
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="style6">
                                  <asp:Label ID="Label3" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Group Name:"></asp:Label>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtgroupname" Visible="false" CssClass="textEntry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="txtgroupname" ValidationGroup="z" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="style6">
                                  &nbsp;</td>
                              <td>
                                  <asp:Button ID="Button2" Visible="false" ValidationGroup="z" runat="server" 
                                      Width="160px" Text="Create New Group" onclick="Button2_Click" />
                                  &nbsp;
                                  <asp:Button ID="Button3" Visible="false" runat="server" Width="160px" 
                                      Text="Cancel" onclick="Button3_Click" />
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>
```

Comment: in the second case the `OkControlID="btnUpdate" ` is not shown and  modal is needed it, maybe this is the issue. Maybe if you redesign your navigations/actions.

Comment: Aristo aderfe exis dikio, efxaristw! Pedevomouna 5 ores.Postare apantisi giana sou dosw tsek. Thank you the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I note on the comments, you have setup the `OkControlID="btnUpdate"` on the `asp:ModalPopupExtender` and that control exist only on the first PlaceHolder. So when you hide the first PlaceHolder you make the modal to fail because is need that button to fully function.